# How can I avoid circular dependencies when calling a method from another assembly using dependency injection in C#?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

How to call a method inside another assembly that you cannot reference?

I'm trying to made a call represented by the red line, but, my domain layer cannot reference my application layer because it will cause a cyclic redundancy, so, looking on internet I found a way to do that loading the assembly, but, I'm not sure if it is the better way to do that

The application use dependency-injection, this is a simplified diagram of the application:

[image: Diagram]

This is the complete implementation of the Domain class

```
public class SomeDomainService<T> : ISomeDomainService<T>
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public SomeDomainService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task<SomeEntity> SomeProcess(SomeEntity someEntity)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            someEntity.Id = new Random().Next(3000);
            someEntity.Name = $"Entity {someEntity.Id}";
            someEntity.Description = "lorem ipsum";
            /*
             * 
             * SOME PROCESS
             * 
            */

            var aplicationAssembly = Assembly.Load("Application");
            var types = aplicationAssembly.GetTypes();
            var type = types.FirstOrDefault(t=> t.Name == "IAnotherApplicationService`1");

            if (type != null)
            {
                var domainMessage = new Message {
                    Id = someEntity.Id.ToString(),
                    Title = $"Some entity {someEntity.Name}",
                    Body = "Message from Domain"
                };


                var runtimeType = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(Message));
                var methods = runtimeType.GetRuntimeMethods();

                var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(runtimeType);

                var method = service.GetType().GetMethod("SendSomeMessage");

                method.Invoke(service, new object[] { domainMessage});
            }

            return someEntity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The general answer to your question (about untangling dependencies) is to use an interface (or interfaces) in another assembly. You implement the interface(s) in one of your assemblies, and you refer to instances of the types you are interested not by the raw type, but by the interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you end with a circular dependency you should consider to refactor your code because something is not placed in the right place.
If the domain service needs to call the application service, consider to move that functionality from the application to the domain layer.